# Create RESTful API in PHP

Tags: php, rest

I have got a big system write in PHP. This system isn't based on any framework. I have decided to create a RESTful API.

1. In there any simple library which helps me build API? And is simple to deploy in my system? I didn't use namespace in my system.
2. Is there any possible to create session with RESTful API? because I need login functionality.
3. It will be great if library which I use to build RESTful API, help me to create documentation

Has someone used RESTler? What do you think about this tool?

Comment: `REST` is stateless, but there's no reason your `PHP` can't maintain session state. Give your `PHP` an authentication token to your `REST` service, and then have users authenticate with your `PHP`.

Comment: I just wrote a simple API system using Slim Framework - you can get away with hooking into its routing system, and then calling your own code from there i.e. you don't have to use all of it.

Comment: CakePHP has inbuilt REST functionality, it's built to automatically handle certain request methods on certain endpoints

Comment: did you look at [propel](http://propelorm.org/) ?

Answer (score 2):

1. A library for a RESTful API is likely to be a microframework. If you are going for a microframework then you could look at a proper framework as well which might have more robust features.
2. For login on REST you can cheat a bit by using HTTP Basic Authentication
3. If you want auto documentation, I would recommend checking out Symfony2 along with the FOSREst Bundle and the NelmioApiDoc Bundle works a treat

for a full explanation check out this article:
http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/